# Datatype .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I´m getting a NaN out of this script, is it a data type problem and how do i solve it?

```
       <script>
            function calc(){
                var profile = document.getElementById("profil");
                var hours = document.getElementById("hour");
               
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=profile*hours;
            }
        </script>
```

Present the result like this

```
               <button onclick="calc()">Calc</button><br>
               <p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: `.getElementById` returns an element and not a number https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Element Object * Element Object = NaN

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the value from the element.

```
var profile = document.getElementById("profil").value;
```

Comment: Thanks!! This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With `.getElementById` you get a DOM Element.

Supposing "profil" and "hour" are input elements, you want to obtain their values:

```
   <script>
        function calc(){
            var profile = document.getElementById("profil").value;
            var hours = document.getElementById("hour").value;
           
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=profile*hours;
        }
    </script>
```